# How to obtain data from a table that has been joined

Tags: python, join, filter, flask, sqlalchemy

I have two tables `items` and `games`.

```
@app.route('/collection/<username>/<int:page>/<platform>/<path:path>')    
def collection(username, page=1, platform='DMG', path=None):
    # first I get the user by his username
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
    # then I get all items form the user and related games
    items = user.items.join(Game)
    # until now it works perfectly fine        
    # now I would like to obtain all titles from the joined table games
    game_titles = items.filter(Game.title).all()
    # but unfortunately I get only an empty list
```

What is missing?

Here my models:

```
class Game(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'games'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True)
    publisher = db.Column(db.String(32), index=True)
    region = db.Column(db.String(3), index=True)
    code_platform = db.Column(db.String(3), index=True)
    code_identifier = db.Column(db.String(4), index=True)
    code_region = db.Column(db.String(3), index=True)
    code_revision = db.Column(db.String(1))
    code = db.Column(db.String(16), index=True, unique=True)
    year = db.Column(db.Integer)

    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    items = db.relationship('Item', backref='game', lazy='dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Game %r>' % (self.title)


class Item(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'items'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    code = db.Column(db.String(8), index=True)
    cart = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    box = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    manual = db.Column(db.Boolean)

    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    game_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('game.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
       return '<Collection %r>' % (self.user_id)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "filter all game titles"?

Comment: @univerio I want all titles in table 'games' which are linked in table 'items'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options. Using SQLAlchemy ORM:

```
game_titles = [i.game.title for i in user.items]
```

To make this more efficient, you can apply the `joinedload` optimization:

```
game_titles = [i.game.title for i in user.items.options(joinedload(Item.game))]
```

Alternatively, you can use SQLAlchemy core if all you care about are the titles (and nothing else):

```
game_titles = user.items.join(Item.game).with_entities(Game.title).all()
```

You can even skip fetching the user altogether if you don't care about the user at all:

```
game_titles = User.query.join(User.items).join(Item.game).filter(User.username == username).with_entities(Game.title).all()
```

As an aside, `.filter` and `.filter_by` correspond to the [selection operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_(relational_algebra)) in relational algebra, whereas `.with_entities` and `db.session.query(...)` correspond to the [projection operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(relational_algebra)), contrary to what you had initially assumed.

Comment: Thanks very much. Both options works perfectly fine. And to get only the distinct ones I would apply `.distinct()` like `user.items.join(Game).with_entities(Game.code_platform).distinct().all()`. Would it also be possible to do that by using SQLAlechemy ORM?

Comment: @ericMTR Not directly. You'll have to do the deduplication in python if you use the ORM (`list(set(game_titles))`).

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
items.join(Game).options(joinedload(Item.game, innerjoin=True))
```

Essentially, you're joining with Game and explicitly loading it, where the innerjoin forces it to do so only on the games listed in the table you're joining with (items)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It works partly. I'm able to filter specific games like `games = items.filter_by(title = 'Adventure Island').all()`. But I still c'ant get all games at once. If I try `games = items.filter(Game.title).all()` I get an empty list. Any suggestion here?

Comment: @ericMTR `filter` does not mean "take the full set of columns and filter it down to only the columns I want". It means "take the full set of **rows** and filter it down to only the **rows** matching the criteria I specified".

Comment: @univerio So how could I possibly accomplish to get all items of a specific column I want? I want all items in column **title** from table **games** based on `items.join(Game).options(joinedload(Item.game, innerjoin=True))`?